# regex pattern for integer with comma

Tags: regex

The pattern

```
$test =  preg_match('/^(?=.\d)\d(?:\.\d\d)?$/', $_float1);
```

matches

```
0.25
2.55
1253.36
45.55
```

How to modify this to accept a comma in between the integer part?
such as 1,253.36?

Comment: Why did you set the JavaScript tag ? This looks more like PHP to me.

Comment: Potential duplicates: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199085/regex-for-optional-comma-separated-number-with-decimal-point) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154386/regex-a-decimal-number-with-comma), but there are numerous other similar questions.

Comment: @dystroy yes its php i will remove the tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would've used this one:

```
/^\d{1,3}(?:(,?)\d{3}(\1\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d{2})?$/
```

Explained:

- `^\d{1,3}`: starts by 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:(,?)\d{3}(\1\d{3})*)?`: [optional] repeat `XXX` or `,XXX` patterns (only one of them, to exclude numbers like 11,111111)
- `(?:\.\d{2})?`: [optional] exactly two decimal places
- `$`: That's all folks

Matches:

1 - 12 - 123 - 1234 - 12345
1,234 - 12,345 - 123,456 - 1,234,567
1.23 - 12.34 - 123.45 - 1234.56 - 12345.67
1,234.56 - 12,345.67 - 123,456.78 - 1,234,567.89

Doesn't match:

.1 - .12 - .123
1.2 - 1.234 - 1.2345
12,34 - 123,45 - 1,2345 - 1,2,345 - 1234,567
12,34.56 - 123,45.67 - 1,2345.78

Answer (score 2):

You could use this pattern:

```
/^\d*(,?\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR2vN7/1)